# Conjugacy classes and characteristic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I was working in $GL(2,p)$ and I was wondering if two matrices are similar iff they have the same characteristic polynomial. One direction is obvious, but I was wondering if it was true that if two matrices have the same characteristic polynomial then they are conjugate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not true in general. For instance, the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ both have $(x-1)^2$ as their characteristic polynomial, but are not similar because they have different minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

This result **is** true if the characteristic polynomial these matrices (let's call them $A$ and $B$) share splits into distinct linear factors; or in other words, $A$ and $B$ share $n$ distinct eigenvalues.  In such a case, $A$ and $B$ are [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), allowing us to write:

$$A = PDP^{-1}$$
$$B = QDQ^{-1}$$

Where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries corresponding to the shared eigenvalues, and $P$ and $Q$ are matrices whose columns are the corresponding eigenvectors.  Rearranging the above, we get both $D = P^{-1}AP$ and $D = Q^{-1}BQ$, which yields $P^{-1}AP = Q^{-1}BQ \implies$ $A = (PQ^{-1})B(QP^{-1})$, so $A$ and $B$ are similar.